# Kendo UI Grid: How To Keep Custom Filter Row In Synch With Column Reordering And Hiding

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

How can I achieve to keep my custom filter row in synch with column reordering and column hiding? I am currently investigating Telerik kendo UI grid v2013.1.514.

The code is as follows:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
        },
        pageSize: 15,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true
    },
    height: 450,
    reorderable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{ field: "ProductID"}, { field: "ProductName"}, { field: "UnitPrice"}]
});

var filterRow = $('<tr><td><input type="search" id="ProductIDSearchBox" value="EnterProductID"/></td>' +
     '<td><input type="search" id="ProductNameSearchDD" value="Enter ProductName"/></td>' +
     '<td><input type="search" id="UnitPriceSearchBox" value="Enter UnitPrice"/></td></tr>');
grid.data("kendoGrid").thead.append(filterRow);
```

Please find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WrqmD/4/.
Just drag'n'drop the column headers around and see that the custom filter row is NOT reordered!

EDIT:

Btw., the solution to append the custom filter is described here: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/grid-header-filtering-row-that-contains-1-element-for-each-column-in-grid-with-the-same-width.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After coresponding with the Telerik Support I would like to share the solutions below:

1. ***Implementing the columnReorder event*** adding the following method declaration to the grid options. This was suggested by Telerik Support. Please find a working JsFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/siliconsoul/y7e7D/1/):

   ```
   columnReorder: function(e) {
     var selector = this.thead.find(".filterRow td"),
     source = selector.eq(e.oldIndex),
     dest = selector.eq(e.newIndex);
     source[e.oldIndex > e.newIndex ? "insertBefore" : "insertAfter"](dest);
   }
   ```
2. ***Append the Custom Elements to the original header elements***. This is my own solution where I go with, because both reordering and hiding of columns is solved with the same code. Please find a working JsFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XxY7j/4/):

   ```
   var columns = grid.data("kendoGrid").columns;
   for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
     var column = columns[i];
     var columnName = column.field;
     var columnHeader = $('div#grid th.k-header[data-field="' + columnName + '"]');
     if(undefined != columnHeader[0]) {
       var fieldValue = $('<input type="text" style="display:block;">');
       fieldValue.val(columnName);
       fieldValue.click(function(evt) {
         evt.stopPropagation();
         $(evt.target).focus().select();
       });
       columnHeader.append(fieldValue);
     }
   }
   ```